# WebView in Fragment doesn't load HTML string

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-webview

I'm passing an HTML string to my Fragment. It loads it into a WebView but nothing happens, the fragment remains empty.

I'm pretty sure (thanks to logs) that my Fragment is receiving the HTML string.

That's the Fragment code:

```
private WebView mWebView;
String html;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, "VideogamesWebViewFragment --> onCreate()");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
    if(bundle != null)
    {
        html = bundle.getString("html");
    }

super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, "VideogamesWebViewFragment --> onCreateView()");
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.default_web_view, container,
            false);
    mWebView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webview);   
    mWebView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);         
    //load html string   
    mWebView.loadData(html, "text/html", null);  

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, "VideogamesWebViewFragment --> onDestroy()");
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, "VideogamesWebViewFragment --> onDestroyView()");
    super.onDestroyView();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, "VideogamesWebViewFragment --> onResume()");
}

@Override
public void onViewStateRestored(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState);  
    Log.d(MainActivity.TAG,"VideogamesWebViewFragment --> onViewStateRestored()");
}
```

I also get these errors:

```
03-07 07:09:41.626: D/Ludos(3053): VideogamesWebViewFragment --> onCreate()
03-07 07:09:41.626: D/Ludos(3053): VideogamesWebViewFragment --> onCreateView()
03-07 07:09:41.636: V/WebViewChromium(3053): Binding Chromium to the background looper Looper{b100af18}
03-07 07:09:41.636: I/chromium(3053): [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(112)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
03-07 07:09:41.636: I/BrowserProcessMain(3053): Initializing chromium process, renderers=0
03-07 07:09:41.666: W/chromium(3053): [WARNING:proxy_service.cc(888)] PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation
03-07 07:09:41.756: D/Ludos(3053): VideogamesWebViewFragment --> onViewStateRestored()
03-07 07:09:41.756: D/Ludos(3053): VideogamesWebViewFragment --> onResume()
03-07 07:09:41.796: W/EGL_emulation(3053): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-07 07:09:41.806: W/AwContents(3053): nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
03-07 07:09:42.076: W/AwContents(3053): nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
03-07 07:09:42.476: E/eglCodecCommon(3053): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
03-07 07:09:42.486: E/eglCodecCommon(3053): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
03-07 07:09:42.546: I/chromium(3053): [INFO:async_pixel_transfer_manager_android.cc(56)] Async pixel transfers not supported
03-07 07:09:42.656: I/chromium(3053): [INFO:async_pixel_transfer_manager_android.cc(56)] Async pixel transfers not supported
03-07 07:09:42.746: E/eglCodecCommon(3053): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
03-07 07:09:42.776: E/eglCodecCommon(3053): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
03-07 07:09:42.786: E/eglCodecCommon(3053): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
03-07 07:09:43.336: E/eglCodecCommon(3053): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
03-07 07:09:43.376: E/eglCodecCommon(3053): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
03-07 07:09:43.386: E/eglCodecCommon(3053): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
03-07 07:09:43.406: E/eglCodecCommon(3053): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
03-07 07:09:43.416: E/eglCodecCommon(3053): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
03-07 07:09:43.426: E/eglCodecCommon(3053): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
03-07 07:09:43.446: E/eglCodecCommon(3053): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
03-07 07:09:43.456: E/eglCodecCommon(3053): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
03-07 07:09:43.476: E/eglCodecCommon(3053): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
03-07 07:09:43.496: E/eglCodecCommon(3053): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
03-07 07:09:43.506: E/eglCodecCommon(3053): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
03-07 07:09:43.516: E/eglCodecCommon(3053): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
03-07 07:09:43.546: E/eglCodecCommon(3053): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
03-07 07:09:43.546: E/eglCodecCommon(3053): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
03-07 07:09:43.566: E/eglCodecCommon(3053): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onCreateView` can be called before or after `onActivityCreated` depending on how you add your Fragment. Try loading the HTML in `onResume` or `onStart`

Comment: I still get the errors in the logcat but now the WebView works!

Comment: now if I click on a Url in the WebView, it doesn't get loaded and it becomes empty. Suggestions?

Comment: I switched from fragment to activity and now it works, thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Don't care about the errors you get from the logcat.

In my case, I loaded a site which contains a Image slider. The logcat produces the same error code when the image in slider is changes the images. I assumed that it might because of the webpage computes the size of the screen of my device. I just gussed because its from gl, Im not sure..

05-03 10:15:25.149: E/eglCodecCommon(5081): **ERROR unknown type 0x1(glSizeof,73)**

But it didn't trouble my app anymore.